# php symfony frequent useless log entry

Tags: php, symfony

In my symfony log I got the following entry

```
[2018-12-20 17:53:19] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: 
"No route found for "GET /js/sprintf.min.map"" at C:\xampp\htdocs\m\var\cache\prod\classes.php line 3958 
{"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): 
No route found for \"GET /js/sprintf.min.map\" at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\m\\var\\cache\\prod\\classes.php:3958,
Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):
at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\m\\var\\cache\\prod\\appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:1114)"} []
```

which does not seem to have any effect. But I would like to remove it from my logs. Tried to search for it but nothing could be found. Any ideas how to get rid of it? Thank you.

Comment: Where cannot it be found? And what do you mean by not having any effect? Also, isn't better to actually fix the cause than trying to get rid of an error message? Looks like an improperly configured web server.

Comment: it is found in symfony log file where all logs are written by default. Not having any effect means that no negative (or positive) impact on web app is caused though it is PHP Exception.

Comment: Well, but you're unable to load the source map file `/js/sprintf.min.map` which significantly helps you to debug client-side code. Again, I would rather properly configure your web server than trying to hide the error message.

Comment: could you please provide some advice, how web server should be configured (relatively to the error described)?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude it from the logger

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            excluded_http_codes: [404]
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_exclude_http_codes.html

Comment: This way you hide all HTTP 404 ("Not Found") log entries so you won't be able to find missing files (or wrong URLs) from Symfony's log file. You would have to use web server's logs.